# Erro ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Tenho este código, a funcionar perfeitamente tal como quero

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="container">
    <form class="well form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID_Reserva)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ID_Cliente, "ID_Cliente", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("ID_Cliente", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID_Cliente, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataEntrada, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataEntrada, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataEntrada, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataSaida, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataSaida, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataSaida, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TipoQuarto, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TipoQuarto, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TipoQuarto, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NumeroQuarto, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NumeroQuarto, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NumeroQuarto, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NumeroNoites, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NumeroNoites, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NumeroNoites, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Preço, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Preço, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Preço, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Observaçoes, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Observaçoes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Observaçoes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
}
```

Contudo, quando tento mudar esse codigo em cima para este codigo,no sentido de mudar o formato ( motivo estético ) da-me o seguinte erro !

Codigo

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="well form-horizontal" action=" " method="post" id="contact_form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Nome Cliente</label>
            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                    <input name="Nome Cliente" class="form-control" value="@Model.Cliente.Nome">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Data Entrada</label>
            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
                    <input name="Data Entrada" class="form-control" value="@Model.DataEntrada">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Data Saída</label>
            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
                    <input name="Data Saída" class="form-control" value="@Model.DataSaida">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Tipo Quarto</label>
            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-hotel"></i></span>
                    <input name="Tipo Quarto" class="form-control" value="@Model.TipoQuarto">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">NºQuarto</label>
            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-hotel"></i></span>
                    <input name="NºQuarto" class="form-control" value="@Model.NumeroQuarto">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">NºNoites</label>
            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-hotel"></i></span>
                    <input name="NºNoites" class="form-control" value="@Model.NumeroNoites">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Preço</label>
            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"></i></span>
                    <input name="Preço" class="form-control" value="@Model.Preço">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Observações</label>
            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="Observações" value="@Model.Observaçoes"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Editar<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Ir para a listagem de Reservas", "Index")
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Ao executar isto da-me este erro

[image: Imagem do Erro]

Entidade

```
namespace WebApplication.Models.BaseDados
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Reserva
    {
        public int ID_Reserva { get; set; }
        public int ID_Cliente { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DataEntrada { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DataSaida { get; set; }
        public string TipoQuarto { get; set; }
        public int NumeroQuarto { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> NumeroNoites { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Preço { get; set; }
        public string Observaçoes { get; set; }

        public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando é dado um `post` em uma `action` de um `controle` que recebe um objeto como parâmetro ele "pega" os dados através do **`name`** das propriedades. Provavelmente o erro ao salvar ocorre porque não está indo os valores preenchidos. Altere os `names` para o mesmo nome da propriedade, exemplo

**Antes:**

```
<input name="Tipo Quarto" class="form-control" value="@Model.TipoQuarto">
```

**Depois:**

```
<input name="TipoQuarto" class="form-control" value="@Model.TipoQuarto">
```

obs: Por que não usar o `razor`, sendo que os `inputs` estão iguais os gerados por ele?

Answer (score 0):

Para ver os erros utilize o seguinte codigo  em  seu  savaChange

```
try
        {
             ... o restante do codigo
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                    eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Value: \"{1}\", Error: \"{2}\"",
                        ve.PropertyName,
                        eve.Entry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(ve.PropertyName),
                        ve.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            throw;
        }
```

Assim  você conseguirar ver quais campos estão ocorrendo erro ao validar, o  seu  erro  não está no  cshtml e sim no  seu arquivo cs muitoprovavel dentro da entidade isso ocorre geralmente quando campos estão com valores null

coloque um breakpoint para ver o retorno nesse codigo que te passei

Comment: Usei isso, mas nao me mostrou os erros ... eu penso que o erro tenha a ver com o ID_Reserva

Comment: vc debugou  na linha deste codigo, costuma não  imprimir  no console tive um erro  similar  a esse

Comment: seria melhor você postar o codigo de seu entity(entidade) ao invez do View

Comment: Eu fiz umas alteraçoes no codigo que me forneceu... agora ja diz o erro. Deu me isto ---> : 'The 'O campo TipoQuarto é necessário.' property does not exist or is not mapped for the type 'Reserva'.'

Comment: Certo, meio  caminho  andado mas  preciso que poste sua entity aqui para ver o campo, se  você estiver usando o fluent api, posta  o  mapping também

Comment: o erro fala que o campo TipoQuarto é necessario mas  não existe ou não está sendo mapeado no entity Reserva, ou seja ele está requisitando um valor que não existe, muito provavel o erro está no relacionamento das suas tabelas ou no  seu  mapeamento,  caso você tenha mapeado esse campo como requerido você tem  que fornece-lo na hora de salvar os dados no banco

Comment: Editei agora a questao e ja coloquei a entidade, o que tenho nela. Quanto ao maping nao percebi o que quer dizer , comecei estes dias em Mvc e ainda estou com dificuldades

Comment: o mapeamento que o @MarcosBrinner quis dizer é se a propriedade TipoQuarto está configurada referente a [DataAnnotation](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/dataannotation-in-code-first.aspx) ou mapping [Fluent API](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-entity-mappings-using-fluent-api.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Levando em conta que o erro foi estourado no `db.SaveChanges()` como `System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException`, recomendo que você verifique o objeto passado no método de `Edit` (`Reserva reserva`). Mas olhando rapidamente o seu `cshtml` modificado e levando em conta que você está fazendo uma edição dos dados já inseridos, falta o Id para alteração.
Por exemplo em sua view antiga apresenta o hidden: `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID_Reserva)`, mas em sua nova view não identifiquei nenhum componente entregando o id para modificação.

**OBS:** Um modo rápido de "visualizar" este problema, seria colocar um breakpoint em seu método e verificar o parâmetro `reserva` para um melhor entendimento do objeto que está sendo alterado.

Comment: acrescentei isto <input type="hidden" id="ID_Reserva" name="ID_Reserva" value="@Model.ID_Reserva" /> mas deu o mesmo erro ...

Comment: @Heftysilva, teria como passar o que está vindo do parâmetro reserva? Que este exception gerado é claramente algo que vai contra o modelo implementado em seu código.

Comment: @DanielNicodemos da uma  lida nos comentarios da minha resposta ele conseguiu identificar o erro que está no TipoQuarto, talvez ajude a achar a solução

Comment: o erro dele é The 'O campo TipoQuarto é necessário.' property does not exist or is not mapped for the type 'Reserva'.'

Comment: Então pode ser uma das situações: 1 - Pode estar mapeado como not null e estar sendo enviado nulo na edição. 2 - Não está mapeado ao modelo a propriedade TipoQuarto.

Comment: @MarcosBrinner, este erro ainda não foge da situação do objeto passado. Seria ótimo se ele publicasse o model `Reserva` e o que está sendo passado neste parâmetro também. Mas o caminho é este mesmo sinalizado, a validação mesmo do modelo ao que está sendo passado pelo parâmetro.

Comment: Já publiquei o Modelo Reserva,

Comment: @Heftysilva Verifique se na passagem do parâmetro `reserva` a propriedade `TipoQuarto` está sendo enviada como `null`

Comment: Nao estou a perceber como posso fazer isso, mas acredito que o problema é mesmo esse !

Comment: @Heftysilva, coloque um breakpoint no método e assim que você chamar este método de editar pressione `SHIFT` + `F9`. Vai aparecer a tela de QuickWatch. Nela você escreve o nome do parâmetro passado (no caso o parâmetro `reserva`) e pressione enter. Dentro deste adicionado, navegue pelas propriedades deste objeto (que no caso você irá pesquisar dentro do parâmetro `reserva` a propriedade `TipoQuarto`)

Comment: Desde já, obrigada pela ajuda!! Acabei de fazer isso e no TipoQuarto aparece como null